# removing clamav with purge leaves database

Tags: apt, disk-usage, clamav

I uninstalled clamav with

```
apt-get remove --purge clamav
```

but still I have this 100MB folder:

```
du -shc /var/lib/clamav
```

Why is this not deleted on purge? And how can I find out if some other installed program still uses this folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clamav` on at least Debian (you don't mention what distro you're using) doesn't contain the database. For that `clamav` has a dependency on `clamav-freshclam | clamav-data` so make sure that both of those are also purged.

Comment: purging those packages will empty the database (though it still leaves a small file `/var/lib/clamav/bytecode.cld`) How did you find out those packages?

Comment: If you look at the [package details](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/clamav) you also find dependencies on `clamav-base clamav-docs libclamav6` I removed them with `apt-get remove --purge clamav*`